# Is there any benefit of having duplicates of a file, in case the HDD crashes?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup, crash

I have a very important folder (around 200 MB) that I want to back up pretty much every week. I simply copy it to *the same* external HDD (with a different folder name).
So I will end up with mostly the same files several times – which is totally fine.

My question is: if the HDD crashes (so I will end up with some bad sectors or whatever), will the fact that I will have 10 or 20 copies of the same file(s) make it easier to recover my files – or, when an HDD crashes, does it usually crash 100%?

EDIT: I'm fine with having several external HDDs. But, will having several copies of my folder on **each** HDD - will that bring any benefit? Or a copy/external HDD would be enough?

Comment: Personal experience, but my crashes have always been 100% fatal. The only time I've been able to recover anything, the HDD was actually still on the verge of permanent failure (and multiple copies would have been a waste of space). You should be making backups on *different media* (CD, another HDD) periodically. I would think that you are likely to be very unhappy with your current solution if/when things eventually fail.

Comment: The fact that you have multiple copies on the same medium may help but does not guarantee anything. It could be the interface to the disk that dies and not just some bad sectors, in which case 1 or 1000 copies will not make a change. You should diversify your backups, and use other options in addition, like remote backups.

Comment: Someone should add an answer to this question from either of the comments or both thus far with a little further detail for clarification.

Comment: Another point: if your files are that important, they really need to be stored off site. That can consist of a safe deposit box where you store an external HDD, or someone's server farm where you upload your backups to. If your house burns down, gets robbed, flooded, destroyed by a tornado, etc., you'll be glad you had off site backups.

Comment: When your primary HDD fails, there is a massively increased chance that your first backup will fail at the same time. As long as you have another backup that isn't so far back in time that you can't remember how to re-do the work, you will be fine - if you are lucky. N.B. RAID is not the same as backup.

Comment: I agree that you really need an off-site backup for anything important, but my experience - and I have done quite a bit of disk recovery - is that hdd's fail gradually and you can often recover data from them. Putting files on different partitions can help as can regular defragmenting - but none of this will help in the case of a typical SSD failure or if the disk is stolen or hit with crypolocker or a most types of fault on the control board - and tedtoring frombackup is easier, faster and less stressful then recovering from a disk crash.

Comment: @davidgo Agreed about storing them offsite. I also edited my question - I'm ok with having several external HDDs. I want to know if having several copies of my folder onto each HDD will bring any benefits, in case of failure. You seem to agree

Comment: @BillDOe Right about the offsite - will definitely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backups are important.  There are a number things you need to consider about backups, and the level of risk that you are comfortable with. There are a few use cases for backups.  The two are are disaster recovery, and mitigation against file corruption.

Disaster recovery is more or less the complete recovery of your environment in the event of a catastrophic failure of your system in some respect.  You can lose your system because of loss of its environment, eg fire, theft, or water damage, in which case having an offsite copy of your data is important.  You can lose data because of system software or hardware failure.

Secondly, recovery from file level corruption is a much harder problem and requires multiple copies of your files being kept backwards in time.  This is a problem that Backblaze and Carbonite do no answer because they only keep versions of your backups for a limited amount of time.

My advice to you be to use a proper backup program and set the retention time and periods to something that you are happy.  For example, we keep upto 5 years of monthly backups, 12 months of weekly backups and 12 weeks of daily backups.  More modern backup systems have deduplication technology, but that comes at the expense of RAM consumption for storage and management of the file-block hash.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'm trying to understand: catastrophic failure vs file level corruption - are there any documented experiments of this, so to understand - what's the likelyhood of one happening vs the other. I'm also fine having several external HDDs if that's what it takes. When you say "5 years of monthly backups" - you basically mean, a new copy of the files each month, so I would end up with 60 copies, yes? Do you keep them on the same HDD, or do you have several?

Comment: Catastrophic failure are situations when complete systems are stop functioning completely.  There are many examples of this, but a hard drive simply not functioning would be a good example.  File level corruption could a symptom of impending complete failure, ie catastrophic failure, or a misbehaved program (or user), or just plain bad dumb luck.  Hard drive manufactures, like most equipment manufactures, rate their drives with MTBF (Mean Time Between Failures).  

There is good chance of both complete failure and file level corruption happening in a 5 year time window, in my opinion.

Comment: Backups are all about risk mitigation.  There are backup programs that will help you manage all of this, deduplicate your data in secure way that prevents bitrot (random bit changes, corrupting data).

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. That's kind of what i wanted to know. In the long run, I'd like to develop something similar to what you automate what you have (5y of monthly backups,12m of weekly backups, 12w of daily backups)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a benefit in having duplicate of files on the same drive?

Yes, but the benefits are marginal.

If the files are very important you need to consider worst case failures, not typical. It may well be that failures on your particular drive tend to be partial and recoverable. But how would that help you if you have a total and non recoverable failure? There are many possible causes for such failures and understand that for a variety of reasons external drives tend to be less reliable than internal. You should hope for the best but prepare for the worst. It may happen.

All files of any importance should have at least one backup copy. But if the files are of particular importance you should have 2 or more backup copies on different media and preferably stored in separate locations. Backup copies do fail and you likely won't notice until they are needed. Backups should be tested to ensure that are good. There have been many cases where people thought they were making backups but there was some kind of unnoticed problem and they had none that were usable.

You should have local backups that are easily accessible in case of need. It is best that these should be to some external device that is connected only during the backup. Always connected devices may be damaged by a power surge or accidental or malicious computer activity.

Off-site backups are always a good idea. What would happen if there was a fire, flood, theft, etc, and all of our local backups were lost along with the external drive with your primary external drive?

Again, hope for the best but prepare for the worst.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Yes, the files are very important. What I want to understand is - assuming the hdd crashes (partially or fully) - what is the chance, in percent, that the crash is fatal? What I want to learn is - **what would be a good ratio of external hdds/copies** to be relatively sure I will be able to restore in case of a problem?

Answer (score 0):

> when an HDD crashes, does it usually crash 100%?

Usually 100%.  I've experienced multiple drive failures over the course of decades.  The most common experience is just that when you turn the computer on, the hard drive doesn't respond to the motherboard.  No such response at all.

Oh, maybe it will respond a bit, in the sense that I might here it try to spin up.  However, since it doesn't successfully start operating, it doesn't give any information to the motherboard.  So, from the motherboard's perspective, it's toast.

So, once toast, everything's lost.

Yes, in theory, two copies could help if one copy was affected by a bad sector.  However, once a drive develops bad sectors, the general consensus I've heard from older experts than me is that such a drive is more prone to develop more bad sectors more quickly.  And at 200MB, your file might be particularly likely to have some fragmentation, possibly being stored in different locations.

So while in theory your approach might help in some scenario, I find it rather unlikely.  Making additional copies to the same drive is effort that is probably better spent in another way that will be more likely to address more common problems that actually occur.

That's the crux of the direct answer to the question.  And now...

**More Rambling:**

At minimum, it is worthwhile to copy the data to at least two devices, even if that is a second drive internal to the computer, or to a USB flash drive, or a writable CD-R disc.  Even this won't be sufficient for area-based disaster scenarios such as spilled water that damages multiple components, but it will at least be more likely to help the most common disaster I've seen, which is a drive just failing to spin up.

Better yet is to get information onto a physically different computer.  (Use networking or other removable media.)

Better yet is to get a friend to store some data at that person's place.  Then if your entire city block goes kapoof but you survive it (perhaps due to not being at home), that data sits.

Large companies back up critical data in multiple cities, and sometimes multiple continents.  Different people may be able to pull something off with different amounts of ease.

While I know many businesses back things up many times throughout a day, my own threshold was a bit lower.  Still, I found it worthwhile to try to make a backup copy outside my home at least once every few days, and especially not more than a couple of weekends (when I tended to do most of my project development).  Because I'd really rather not need to repeat all that work just because I didn't take a bit of time to make a better copy.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'm totally ok with having several external HDDs. I just want to know if having the same file duplicated several times on each external HDD will bring any improvement in case of a failure.